# pdf and document browser ( like image browser but for pdf )

Tags: pdf, filemanager

I have a lot of pdf files ( research papers, presentations ... ) and I download or make by myself lot of them each week. I need something to browse trough them fast and to manage them (like sort them manually, find what to delete, what to put in copy to particular directory).

It is not so convenient to browse it by standard file manager and open each file separatelly in okular or other pdf viewer. I also use [Mendelay](http://www.mendeley.com/) for archiving and organizing my research papers, but it is it's to specialized, and not optimal for this job (eg. I don't what to import all the .pdf into mendelay jut to delete 90% ot it in after few seconds)

I would really like something like image browoser (eg. 
[image: like this Gwenview] )
that in lower bar would be thumbnails of .pdf and in the central area would be the content, and it would be browse very quicky over all pdf in a directory on my disk.

It would be also great if such browser would be generalized also to other documents ( postscript, Libreoffice and MS office presentations (.ddp, .ppt) and text ( .odt, .doc ) ossibly also spreadsheeats ( .ods, .xls ) and simple textfiles and source files ( .txt, .cpp, .f90, .java, .py ... ) )

Comment: [GNOME Documents](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=names&keywords=gnome-documents) seems to be a match, but my user experience is negative. Should anyone or OP can figure out how to make it work properly, feel free to post that as an answer with details.

Answer (score 0):

"converseen" program claims itself to be able to manage PDF and EPDF files, as seen on:
http://converseen.fasterland.net/what-formats-are-supported-by-converseen/

I haven't tried myself, but you can give it a try. I hope it helps.